# Missing Invitations in Game Center Sandbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, game-center, gamekit

I'm experiencing the strangest behavior with Game Center.

I'm setting up turn-based matches with `GKTurnBasedMatch` and friends. Authentication of the local player works perfectly. Using the `GKTurnBasedMatch` class method  `loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:` seems to sensibly return `GKTurnBasedMatch` objects. To initiate new matches and invites to Game Center friends, I use the standard `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController`.

When I create matches with `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController`, they show up there when the `showExistingMatches` property is `YES`, for the game creator.

However, if I invite another player using `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController`, the receiving player never receives an invite. No Game Center push notification, and no (except once or twice, and sporadically) game with an "Invited" heading in the `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController`.

Strangely enough, that player WILL receive a "Game Over" Game Center notification if the initiating user then ends the game they created with an invite.

Using `loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:`, the returned `matches` make sense for the inviting player (correct `playerID` values in the `participant`s, correct `GKTurnBasedParticipantStatus` on the `participant`s), but nothing shows up at all for the invited player.

I'm using two separate devices, both are definitely logged into the Sandbox mode of Game Center, and everything is set up in iTunes Connect, etc. Both Game Center accounts are set to accept invites.

Anyone ever seen anything like this?

Comment: Are you subscribing to the `GKTurnBasedEventHandlerDelegate`? I'm not sure if that's your issue, as I think the delegate messages for that are initiated from the GameCenter app itself. Just another edge case to look out for.

Comment: Good suggestion. My problem was all way before handling anything. The push notifications from Game Center themselves weren't showing up, which was the weird part. I think I've solved the issue (see answer). Now comes the work of making sure when they DO come they are properly handled with `GKTurnBasedEventHandlerDelegate` and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution: when the inviter made their first move, and the message `endTurnWithNextParticipants:turnTimeout:matchData:completionHandler:` was sent, I wasn't sending the proper participants in the first argument, and so the turn was never set to be the invitee's.